# Send email to List of addresses

Tags: apex, email, compile-error

Please help with the syntax for my `message.toAddresses` accepts a List.
Error message

```
Initial expression is of incorrect type, expected: String but was: List<String>
```

My Code:

```
List<AggregateResult> AggregateResultList = [SELECT AccountId, Account.Name name, COUNT(Id) co
                                         FROM Case
                                         WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7
                                         GROUP BY AccountId, Account.Name
                                         HAVING COUNT(Id)  >= 8];

                         Set<Id> AcctIds = new Set<Id>();
                for(AggregateResult aggr: AggregateResultList){

                    Id accId = (Id)aggr.get('AccountId');
                        AcctIds.add(accId);
                }

                List<Case> caseList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name,Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Implementation_status__c,
                                                Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.PM_Implementation_Status__c, 
                                                Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.RCM_Implementation_Status__c    
                                       FROM Case
                                       WHERE AccountId IN :AcctIds];
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            for(Case cl:caseList){ 

                if(cl.Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Implementation_status__c == 'Live - Closed Project'){    
                        //Private method *** getAddresses() *** retrieves email address from Customer_Success_Managers Public Group
                             message.toAddresses = new String[] { getAddresses() }; 
                        }
                        else{  
                            message.toAddresses = new String[] { Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c  };
                        }
                    message.Subject = 'Subject Test Message';
                    message.PlainTextBody = 'Account name: ' + aggr.get('name') + ' has ' + (Integer)aggr.get('co') + ' cases opened in the last 8 days.';
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages =   new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
                    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
            }

private List<String> getAddresses(){
List<User> UserList =
        [SELECT id, name, email
        FROM User 
        WHERE id 
        IN (SELECT userorgroupid 
            FROM groupmember
            WHERE group.name = 'Customer Success Managers')];

List<String> emailString = new List<String>();

for(User u: UserList){
    emailstring.add(u.email);
}   
return (emailString);
}
```

Comment: what line is the error on?

Comment: Line: 25, Column: 56

Comment: Does it work if Implementation_Status__c is not equal to "Live - Closed Project"?

Comment: No, it does not.  Same error.  Even when I try  message.toAddresses = List<String> { getAddresses() }; '  I get the error:  `Line: 25, Column: 56
Unexpected token 'List'.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is

```
message.toAddresses  = new String[] { getAddresses() };
```

should be

```
message.toAddresses  = getAddresses(); // returns a list of email addrs
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the following

```
message.toAddresses = new String[] { getAddresses() }; 

private List<String> getAddresses()
```

You're returning a list of email address and trying to insert it into an array as one value. That's why it's expecting a String (only one string per value in the List).

Assign the returned list directly to the toAddresses:

```
message.ToAddresses = getAddresses();
```

For the else statement, I think you have a typo, you're missing cl in front of the variable.

```
message.toAddresses = new String[] { cl.Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c  };
```